# Trying to solve for A: A=X+YAZ

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been trying to solve this problem  $$A=X+YAZ, \qquad A,X,Y,Z\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$ 
, where $A$ is the only unknown matrix, assuming all matrices are invertible.

Is this possible? If yes, how can it be done, if not, why? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite this as
$$
A = X + YAZ\\
A - YAZ = X\\
Y^{-1}A - AZ = Y^{-1}X
$$
This is now a [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) for $A$.

This system will be uniquely solvable for all $X$ if and only if $Y^{-1}$ and $Z$ have no common eigenvalues.